# convert column of a sheet to value only (remove formulas)

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me out with below formula? It gives object defined or app defined error. Thanks a lot.

```
Sub cellstovalues()

    Sheets("Parsing").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can simply assign the values to the `Value2` (or `Value`) property of the range:

```
Sub cellstovalues()
    With Sheets("Parsing")
        With Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange)
            .Value2 = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

or for a specific range:

```
Sub cellstovalues()
    With Sheets("Parsing").Range("B1:C10")
         .Value2 = .Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is having issues from you selecting the entire column `B`. Try using this. This should find the last used cell in your column, then copy and paste to convert the formulas to values like you want.

```
Sub cellstovalues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parsing")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(LastRow, "B"))
    End With
    rng.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```